# How to use a crate from a cargo workspace on github as a dependency?

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo

Within the [`crates`](https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui/tree/main/crates) directory of the repo, there are [`sui-keys`](https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui/tree/main/crates/sui-keys), [`sui-core`](https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui/tree/main/crates/sui-core), and others. Within my `Cargo.toml` file, how do I specify that I want the `sui-keys` crate as a dependency to my own crate?

```ini
[dependencies.sui-keys]
sui-keys = { git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui" }
```

The above doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a "sui-keys" too many in there, either remove it from the section header:

```ini
[dependencies]
sui-keys = { git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui" }
```

or directly provide the contents for `dependencies.sui-keys`:

```ini
[dependencies.sui-keys]
git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui"
```

I would avoid such mistakes by letting cargo figure it all out:

```bash
cargo add --git="https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui" sui-keys
```

Comment: PS F:\rust_projects\suisdk> cargo add sui-keys --git="https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui"
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui`

Comment: I tried running the above command but it gave this error:

Comment: error: Unrecognized dependency source for `sui-keys`

Comment: What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Not sure, it works for me, I actually ran it with `--git` first but that shouldn't matter I think.